# WPF: get the key of a dictionary from comboboxitem of combobox while hovering over it

Tags: c#, wpf

I am binding a dictionary to my itemssource of a combobox and I am displaying the key of it.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding dictionary}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" />
```

my dictionary looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary
```

Now I wanted to get the key of the comboboxitem I am hovering over:

```
ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(item.Content.ToString()))
```

My problem now is that item.Content.ToString() returns this:

```
[ mykey, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]
```

How do I properly get mykey (and the corresponding value)?

Comment: Set `SelectedValuePath` to `"Key"`, then get the selected item's key by `(string)comboBox.SelectedValue`

Comment: How are you getting the element you're hovering over? That seems a event callback, which event are you picking?

Comment: @Clemens your approach works only for the selected item... I want sth that works while I am hovering over my comboboxitems. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Then you should probably change the question title.

Comment: @Magnetron i am using the mousemove event

Comment: @Clemens oh sorry my bad

Comment: my (probably) bad attempt on solving this is, that I am binding my itemssource to a variable that contains only the keys and then I search my Dictionary for the appropriate string...

Comment: Cast `item.Content` or `item.DataContext` to `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>`

Comment: Great thank you @Clemens